# How to setup nlog.config to use correct directory separator when run on windows or linux

Tags: c#, nlog

I do microservices with NLog logging. The nlog.config file has

`<target xsi: type = "File" name = "web" fileName = "logs\nlog-web-${shortdate}.log" ... />`

`fileName` has the correct path to the logs on windows, but incorrect on linux.

How to set the dynamic value of `fileName` or change "\" to "/" depending on the OC on which the application is running?

Comment: The solution is to always use `/`. It works on Windows and Linux. Ex. `fileName="logs/nlog-web-${shortdate}.log"`

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks, it turned out so easy)

Answer (score 1):

As @rolf-kristensen suggested, `/` can be used since it works in both Windows and Unix-based systems.

However, in Windows the standard path separator is `\`, and there's no telling if there's an operating system that requires a different path separator, so using `/` seems like a hack.

The purist way of dealing with this is to use the [${dir-separator}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Directory-separator) layout renderer.